# program allows you specify points in N-dimensional space

Tags: java

So here is the gist of the assignment I am having difficulty with:

- Write a java class called Point to represent a N-Dimensional point (With coordinates that are double)

  - The constructor should take any number of coordinates
  - The class should have accessor method for any coordinates
  - Write toString() and copy() and equals() helper methods
  - Keep track of every created poin
  - Write a java class called Line to represent a line (with a starting point and an ending point)
  - The constructor arguments are the start and end points
  - The constructor MUST throw an error when the 2 points are not of the same dimension
  - Write a toString() and copy() and equals() helper method
  - Provide a getLineLength() method - Look up "Euclidian Distance" on wiki
  - Keep track of every created line

So i have created my line and point class but I am not sure if I am creating my line or point class correctly. I already have my main method designed to take input from the console and store that input into two different arrays for the coordinates. When i try to call this method in my main to print the coordinates and distance i get back the output:

The distance between ( 4.0 , 5.0 ) 
( 2.0 , 3.0 ) 
( 0.0 , 0.0 ) 
 is>

So I was hoping i could get help in clarifying if I am creating my constructor and everything else correctly. Here is my code for both classes thus far:

```
public class Point{

  private double[] coordinate1;
  private double[] coordinate2;


  public Point(double[] array1, double[] array2){
    this.coordinate1 = array1;
    this.coordinate2 = array2;
  }
  //method to get array inputs and copy them
  public void copy(double[] points1, double[] points2){

    double[] coordinate1 = new double[points1.length +1];
    for(int copyIndex = 0; copyIndex < points1.length; copyIndex++){
      coordinate1[copyIndex] = points1[copyIndex];
    }
    points1 = coordinate1;

    double[] coordinate2 = new double[points2.length +1];
    for(int copyIndex = 0; copyIndex < points2.length; copyIndex++){
      coordinate2[copyIndex] = points2[copyIndex];
    }
    points2 = coordinate2;
  }
  //method to print the coordinates
  public void printArray(){

    double array1 = coordinate1.length;
    double array2 = coordinate2.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < array1 && i < array2; i++) {
      System.out.println("( " + coordinate1[i] + " , " + coordinate2[i] + " ) ");
    }
  }
}


public class Line{

  private double[] coordinate1;
  private double[] coordinate2;
  private double distance;

  public Line(double[] array1, double[] array2){
    this.coordinate1 = array1;
    this.coordinate2 = array2;
  }
  public double getLine(double[] coordinate1, double[] coordinate2){
    double diffSquareSum = 0.0;
    for(int i=0;i<coordinate1.length;i++) {
      diffSquareSum += (coordinate1[i] - coordinate2[i]) * (coordinate1[i] - coordinate2[i]);
    }
    distance = Math.sqrt(diffSquareSum);
    return distance;
  }
  public String toString(){
    return "The distance is " + distance;
  }
}
```

Please let me know if I need to clarify or expand on my question. Appreciate any help. Thank you. 
Here is the output expected from the program once ran:

Example:

Enter point # 1 dimension # 1 or "Random" or "Exit" or "Help" or blank line to proceed: 3.14
Enter point # 1 dimension # 2 or "Random" or "Exit" or "Help" or blank line to proceed: 0
Enter point # 1 dimension # 3 or "Random" or "Exit" or "Help" or blank line to proceed:

Enter point # 2 dimension # 1 or "Random" or "Exit" or "Help" or blank line to proceed: 0
Enter point # 2 dimension # 2 or "Random" or "Exit" or "Help" or blank line to proceed: hEl

- This program allows you specify points in N-dimensional space:

  - Each point can have different number of non-zero coordinate
  - You may request a random number for any coordinate by typing "RANDOM"
  - When you are finished entering the cordinate just press the  key
- Pairs of point are used to create a lines

  - If the 2 points have mismatched dimensions and error will be shown
  - When a line is created, the line distance is provided
- When you are done specifying points and lines type "EXIT" to display final operation statistics
- All key words are case insensitive and can be abreviated
- Random number will be scaled between -1,000.00 and +1,000.00

Enter point # 2 dimension # 2 or "Random" or "Exit" or "Help" or blank line to proceed: 2.71
Enter point # 2 dimension # 3 or "Random" or "Exit" or "Help" or blank line to proceed:
The distance between ( 3.14 , 0.0) and ( 0.0 , 2.71) is 4.147734321289154

Enter point # 1 dimension # 4 or "Random" or "Exit" or "Help" or blank line to proceed: Random
--> -75.1234
Enter point # 1 dimension # 5 or "Random" or "Exit" or "Help" or blank line to proceed:
Enter point # 2 dimension #1 or "Random" or "Help" or "Exit" or blank line to proceed:  RA
--> 38.12851983534693
Enter point # 2 dimension #2 or "Random" or "Help" or "Exit" or blank line to proceed:  rAnD
--> 74.31366638262983

Enter point # 2 dimension #3 or "Random" or "Help" or "Exit" or blank line to proceed:
Ouch - You tried to create a line with points of disimilar dimension!

Enter point # 1 dimension # 1 or "Random" or "Exit" or "Help" or blank line to proceed: EXIT

You created 4 points:
  ( 3.14 , 0.0 )
  ( 0.0 , 2.71 )
  ( -75.1234 )
  ( 38.12851983534693 , 74.31366638262983 )
You created 1 lines:
  ( 3.14 , 0.0 ) to ( 0.0 , 2.71 ) with length 4.147734321289154

So it keeps asking for coordinate doubles and creates a line and then prints out all lines made once program closes. Hope that helps clarify what the assignment requires

Comment: I would have expected Point to only contain one double[] field named coordinates. Why are there two?

Comment: As I understood the task, it requires what kreinerjm stated in his answer. You can realize this with the constructor from Andrew S's answer. The behaivor of copy is indeed not defined, but I guess it should behave like `clone()`. 'Keep track of every created line' is also a bit confusing. What are you required to do? Add the information tom your question.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear why your constructor would have 2 arrays - it seems there should be only 1 array to represent all of the N possible axes.

Also, it's not clear how the coordinates should be passed to the constructor.

Like this using multiple arguments?

```
public class Point {
    private double[] coordinates;

    public Point(double...coordinates) {
        this.coordinates = coordinates;
    }
}
```

Or like this using an array?

```
public class Point {
    private double[] coordinates;

    public Point(double[] coordinates) {
        this.coordinates = coordinates;
    }
}
```

The copy method should likely have this signature:

```
Point copy();
```

so that you return a copy of the current instance.

The requirement for the Line class indicates the constructor takes two `Point`s so it should look similar to this:

```
public Line(Point p1, Point p2);
```

and the methods working with `p1` and `p2`.

Answer (score 1):

You only need one array to represent each point. The length of the array would tell you the dimension of that point. Your code is basically a hard coded 2D point. Correct usage should look something like this:

```
double[] coordinate1 = {0.0};// 1d coordinate
double[] coordinate2 = {0.0,1.0};// 2d coordinate
double[] coordinate3 = {0.0,1.0,2.0};// 3d coordinate

Point point1 = new Point(coordinate1);// 1d point
Point point2 = new Point(coordinate2);// 2d point
Point point3 = new Point(coordinate3);// 3d point

int dimension = point1.getCoordinates().length;
```

Your line class will have two variables of type Point passed in through the constructor. You can make two quick methods

```
public boolean isSameDimension(Point p1, Point p2)
{
    if(p1.getDimension() == p2.getDimension())
        return true;
    return false;
}

public int getDimension()//In point class
{
    return getCoordinates().length;
}
```